# How to get directions on the iPhone or iPad

Tags: iphone, direction

Hi I would like to in my application display something like: you're destination is 400 ft north west.

I currently use the getDistanceFrom method but that only gives me the feet between 2 locations.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably should simply use Latitude Longitude equations to calculate the bearing and then set certain ranges of bearings to be SW,S,SE, etc.

http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Comment: The code here might be useful "Core Location extensions for bearing and distance" http://www.thismuchiknow.co.uk/?p=120