# Find Direction in iphone like North or etc

Tags: iphone, objective-c, direction

I have one trouble in my app i want to know the direction to the Latitude and Longtitude from the current Lat & Long

```
-(void)showDirection
{
 CGFloat latitude = Lat;
 if (latitude < 0) {
    latitude = -latitude;
    strDirection = @"S";
 } else {
    strDirection = @"N";
 }
 // Longitude
 CGFloat longitude = Long;
 if (longitude < 0) {
    longitude = -longitude;
    strDirection = @"W";
 } else {
    strDirection = @"E";
 }
 NSLog(@"direc %@",strDirection);
}
```

Comment: HOpe this link can solve your problem properly,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/412256/can-the-iphone-determine-if-youre-facing-north-south-east-or-west

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get directions on the iPhone or iPad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630789/how-to-get-directions-on-the-iphone-or-ipad)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this code below:

first add framework in your project **CoreLocation.Framework** after adding initialize CLLocationManager object and import CLLocationManager header file.

Yourviewcontroller.h

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
@interface Yourviewcontroller :UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{
      CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}
```

Yourviewcontroller.m

```
locationManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
locationManager.delegate = self;
//Start the compass updates.
[locationManager startUpdatingHeading];
```

add function for get current direction

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading
{
    float mHeading = newHeading.magneticHeading;
    if ((mHeading >= 339) || (mHeading <= 22)) {
        //[direction setText:@"N"]; 

    }else if ((mHeading > 23) && (mHeading <= 68)) {
        //[direction setText:@"NE"];    

    }else if ((mHeading > 69) && (mHeading <= 113)) {
        //[direction setText:@"E"]; 

    }else if ((mHeading > 114) && (mHeading <= 158)) {
        //[direction setText:@"SE"];

    }else if ((mHeading > 159) && (mHeading <= 203)) {
        //[direction setText:@"S"]; 

    }else if ((mHeading > 204) && (mHeading <= 248)) {
        //[direction setText:@"SW"];    

    }else if ((mHeading > 249) && (mHeading <= 293)) {
       // [direction setText:@"W"];

    }else if ((mHeading > 294) && (mHeading <= 338)) {
       // [direction setText:@"NW"];

     }
}
```

**Note :compass is work only real iphone device,not work in iphone simulator..!**

Answer (score -4):

You could try [LocateMe](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LocateMe/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007801-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2). It will give you the long and lat of the user's current position.
Or your could try looking at this [tutorial](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/getting-your-location-in-an-iphone-application)

Hope this helps!